# Unordered list beside paragraph, on same level, without overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an unordered list beside a paragraph being used as a subtitle, however the list is squashed into the size of one item and items are then stacked on top of each other.

I would also like them to both be side by side on the same level, but both aligned to the left and right sides of the header element, respectively.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Zz6Xs/) what I've got so far. You can see the stacked list as well as an attempt to have them side by side, however I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

This is what I've tried to have the subtitle and list on the same level (also look at the jsfiddle):

```
.subtitle {
    ..
    margin-top: -40px;
    ..
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be floating just the `li`. You have to inline your `p` and float `nav` to the right http://jsfiddle.net/Zz6Xs/12/

```
nav {
   float: right; 
}

.subtitle {
    display: inline;
    ...

nav ul {
    margin-top: 0;    
}
```

There are default padding and margin settings that are applied to most HTML elements and they differ from browser to browser. Many people use a [CSS reset syste](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)m to get a consistent look and feel across browsers. See [this example,](http://jsfiddle.net/Zz6Xs/13/) just like what you had, but with having to reset margins yourself

What's even better than using floats is the [flex box model](http://jsfiddle.net/Zz6Xs/15/) if you can use HTML 5. In the following example, we tell the `nav` to take up all remaining space while `p` is only wide as it needs to be

CSS

```
section {
     display: box;  
     box-orient: horizontal;    
}

nav  {
      box-flex: 1;
      text-align: end;
}
```

HTML

```
<section>    
    <p class="subtitle">Subtitle </p>
    <nav><ul>
        <li class="menu">Item 1</li>
        <li class="menu">Item 2</li>
        <li class="menu">Itemmm</li>
    </ul></nav>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed the issue with the list, however is there a way I can get rid of the gap between the header and the subtitle and menu?

Comment: Remove bottom margin for the `h1`

Comment: Thank you! That's everything sorted now.

Comment: @Matthew My edited answer has information about margins and padding that should be useful to you

Comment: Thanks for that information- I was aware of some default padding and margins but not what they were applied to. Thanks for the reset system too, I was unaware of such a thing. I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Also try dropping the negative margins and zero out the padding and margins on the elements.

```
header {
    width: 50% ;
    margin:0 auto;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #33B5E5;
}

h1,p,nav,ul{
        padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.subtitle {
    color: #33B5E5;
    float:left;
    width:20px
}
ul{
    float:right;
}

.menu {
    display: inline;
    width: 20%;
}
```